# The blade doesn't display some data or table

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason my blade page failed to display the websites which are "up", event though it is able to display for down and disabled websites. the codes are identical codes. i would appreciate any suggestion.

```
<tbody>
        @foreach($notes as $notification)
            <?php $notificationHealth = $notification->status('health'); ?>
            <?php $notificationSpeed = $notification->status('speed'); ?>
            @if ((is_null($active) || $notification->active == $active) && (empty($health) || ($health === 'down' && empty($notificationHealth['value'])) || $notificationHealth['value'] === $health))

                <tr> 
                    <td> {{ $notification->website_url }} </td>

                   @if($notificationHealth !== false)
                        @if(\App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) == 'up')
                            <td> {{ \App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) }} <span class="up"></span><br><span class="timestamp_green">{{  $notificationHealth['timestamp'] }}</span></td>.
                        @elseif(\App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) == 'down')
                            <td> {{ \App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) }}  <span class="down"></span><br><span class="timestamp_red">{{ $notificationHealth['timestamp'] }}</span></td>
                        @else
                            <td> {{ \App\Notification::health($notificationHealth['value']) }}  <span class="unsigned"></span><br><span class="timestamp_unsigned">{{ $notificationHealth['timestamp'] }}</span></td>
                        @endif
                    @else
                        <td> N/A <span class="unsigned"></span></td>       
                    @endif
```

this is the snap page

Comment: check your `\storage\logs\laravel.log` see if there's an error that could be the reason

Comment: If they're all showing down, try echoing/logging the values in your IF statement so you can see which ones aren't triggering like it should

Comment: @aynber i cant echo or var_dump in the blade page. Is there another function that helps me to debug. MOre over the log file has no error.

Comment: Take advantage of the log file. `<?php Log::info("Check ifs: {$notification->active} == $active - $health === 'down' - {$notificationHealth['value']} === $health"); ?>` Tweak this as needed. This should go right above your if statement.